# svn copy:how to ignore files not under version control

Tags: svn, svnignore

I want to use `svn copy` to create a new tag,but I have some files are not under control(e.g.:some js files which are generated by coffeescript).`svn copy` command will abort and display error: `error: <file> is not under version control.`

My Question is:how to ignore files which are not under version control when I run `svn copy`?

My command is `svn copy trunk/* tags/2014-08-18/`

Comment: What are the source and the destination of `svn copy`?

Comment: have you properly setup `svn:ignore` for those files/directories?

Comment: Show `svn st` for trunk before copy attempt - it seems you have some not ignored files

Comment: @AdrianShum @LazyBadger Thank you for your comment.I have set `svn:ignore`,when I use `svn st`,it show many files start by a question mark.I can get a list of ignore patterns when I use `svn prophet svn:ignore`.

Comment: @RSahu My command is `svn copy trunk/* tags/2014-08-18/`

Comment: So...there is no way to achieve what OP is asking?

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard (trunk/*) will expand to all files inside that directory. If you have unversioned files svn will fail to copy them and abort.

Solution 1:

- Remove the wildcard: `svn cp trunk dest`.

Solution 2:

- List only the versioned files to copy: `svn cp trunk/a.txt trunk/b.txt dest`.

Comment: The solution 2 is great, except if I need to copy files from a set of different folders, e.g. `src\a\1.txt` to `dst\a\1.txt` plus `src\a\2.txt` to `dst\a\2.txt` plus `src\b\1.txt` to `dst\b\1.txt`. I don't want to copy files one-by-one because copying even the whole `src` to `dst` using a single `svn cp` works much faster then one `svn cp` for each file (when there's a lot of files).